# Generating a verifiable non-sequential integer from a salt in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, signing

The problem: I have to generate an *n*-digit account number. To aid early validation of the number before checking this against any persistency, I want to verify that the number is one of ours. The [Luhn Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) will validate that the number matches a checksum, but not that the issuer of the number is valid.

Example of how this would (ideally) occur:

1. Generate a sequential account number.
2. Hand over sequential number to account number generator:

---

```
$accountNumber = 1; // doesn't matter, could be random
$generator = new Generator(getenv('ACCOUNT_SALT'));
echo $generator->generate($code); // output something like 83463476
```

Later:

```
$badCode = 83463475; // can't be right
$generator = new Generator(getenv('ACCOUNT_SALT'));
$generator->validate($badCode); // will return false because the number cannot be reached mathematically based on the salt.
```

While this is no defence against brute forces, it does give early validation and should give us non-sequential account numbers. The question is: does anyone know an algorithm that would do this, and if so, are they able to give an example?

Comment: Thank you Jay for the edit.

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm confused by probably the most important point - what do you mean by "validate the *issuer* of the number"?

Comment: Taking a (very) basic and undesired approach, imagine that an organisation said one day "all our eight digit account numbers will be multiples of three". Any account number that came in via a form that was _not_ divisible by three would - without even a database lookup - clearly be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I modified the standard One-Time Password implementation I've seen for Two-Factor authentication and used that. Rather than use a counter or timer, we use a number incrementing in sequence, and use that in an HMAC-based library that turns the generated HMAC into a "two factor code".

There are collisions with 8 digits, but we can discard those from generation. What it means is that all accounts are non-sequential, and, if we know the original seed that generated the account number, we can quickly test any account number for integrity at the source rather than check in a database. Account numbers that pass are not necessarily good, but ones that fail are clearly bad.

It does make me wonder if the last three digits on the back of a credit card are in some way similar to this system, and the 12 digits on the front after an issuer something akin to this.